# Delete specific line from a text file which I don't have the name

Tags: c#

I need to find and delete all lines which contain the word "recto",

I did search in stackoverflow forum, but all what I found is do that (delete the line) using path (Directory & FileName).

in my case I want to delete the line contain "recto" in all files with specific extension (*.txt) in the directory.

thanks for help

here is my code so far

```
            string sourceDir = @"C:\SRCE\";
        string destinDir = @"C:\DIST\";
        string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
        foreach (string file in files)
        {
            using (StreamReader sr_ = new StreamReader
            (sourceDir + Path.GetFileName(file)))
            {
                string line = sr_.ReadLine();
                if (line.Contains("recto"))
                {
                    File.Copy(file, destinDir + Path.GetFileName(file));
                    string holdName = sourceDir + Path.GetFileName(file);
                }
                sr_.DiscardBufferedData();
                sr_.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you want to delete? or copy the files that don't contain the word to a different directory?

Comment: Hell  Zinov , what i want is modify (delete line) and copy new files to next directory

Comment: How big are these text files?

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this. You were only identifying the files with the word but not making any try to remove it. At the end, you were copying the files that included the word "recto"

```
            string sourceDir = @"C:\SRCE\";
            string destinDir = @"C:\DIST\";
            string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
            foreach (string file in files)
            {
                using (StreamReader sr_ = new StreamReader
                (sourceDir + Path.GetFileName(file)))
                {
                    string res = string.Empty;

                    while(!sr_.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        var l = sr_.ReadLine();

                        if (l.Contains("recto"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }

                        res += l + Environment.NewLine;
                    }

                    var streamWriter = File.CreateText(destinDir + Path.GetFileName(file));
                    streamWriter.Write(res);
                    streamWriter.Flush();
                    streamWriter.Close();
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the files are not really big you can simplify a lot your code reading all lines in memory, processing the lines with Linq and then rewriting the files

```
string sourceDir = @"C:\SRCE\";
string destinDir = @"C:\DIST\";
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceDir);
foreach (string file in files)
{
    var lines = File.ReadLines(file);
    var result = lines.Where(x => x != "recto").ToArray();
    File.WriteAllLines(Path.Combine(destinDir, Path.GetFileName(file)), result);
}
```